# Rails ActionMailer - a way to support subfolders for mail templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, subdirectory

Is there a way to have subfolders for actionmailer email templates?

```
  def new_message(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "You have recieved a new message!")
  end
```

would load /app/mailers/new_message.text.erb for example.
Is there a way to have the mail templates stored like /app/mailers/messages/new_message.text.erb?

I try to organize it a bit more and don't like everything in 1 big directory ( think of the text and html versions + several local _en, _fr versions this becomes one big pile of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can actually do that, but I am sure you can create multiple ActionMailer classes like a Notifier:

`class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base`

And define the notifications methods here (welcome messages, changing password, ...: auto messages)

With that you can segment your "Mail methods" in different models, depending on their roles.

I know it does not answer the question, but its a workaround ;)

Comment: yes but they would still be not in /mailer/subfolder right? this would just scope them keeping the problem of all files in 1 folder but thx for suggestion

Comment: I followed the default rails convention in the end /app/views/mailer_something

Comment: followed you suggestion in the end wich is rails best practice, stil lhad to set this as accepted answer since there seems no other way ( and fighting conventions is bad anyway )